# Concrete Operational Transformation Algorithm of Etherpad(-Lite)?

Tags: node.js, etherpad, operational-transform

Can me someone provide a hint or a source to the concrete ot-algorithm that is used in etherpad or etherpad lite? Does it base on an academical paper? Also a hint or an link to the part of the source code which does the transformation-part is welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[The Etherpad Wiki has docs on changesets](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/wiki/Changeset-Library) and [Etherpad Operational Transforms documentation](https://github.com/ether/etherpad-lite/blob/develop/doc/easysync/easysync-full-description.pdf), to review the code you want the [source code for the Changeset library](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ether/etherpad-lite/develop/src/static/js/Changeset.js).

It's worth noting that Etherpad uses the same javascript code server and client side for operational transforms.

Should you have any further questions perhaps ask them on the [Etherpad developers mailing list so you hit the correct audience](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/etherpad-lite-dev).

Disclaimer and for posterity: I'm the founder of the [Etherpad Foundation](http://etherpad.org), a not for profit with a goal of supporting the Etherpad software and community.

Comment: Great. That's what i was looking for!